Install apache nifi on Docker failson FlowFile Repository
I can't make Apache nnifi working in Docker.
The problem is a looping at this stage of the installation:
2024-12-19 09:58:15,319 INFO [Checkpoint FlowFile Repository] o.a.n.c.r.WriteAheadFlowFileRepository Initiating checkpoint of FlowFile Repository
2024-12-19 09:58:15,319 INFO [Checkpoint FlowFile Repository] o.a.n.c.r.WriteAheadFlowFileRepository Successfully checkpointed FlowFile Repository with 0 records in 0 milliseconds
2024-12-19 09:58:35,319 INFO [Checkpoint FlowFile Repository] o.a.n.c.r.WriteAheadFlowFileRepository Initiating checkpoint of FlowFile Repository
2024-12-19 09:58:35,319 INFO [Checkpoint FlowFile Repository] o.a.n.c.r.WriteAheadFlowFileRepository Successfully checkpointed FlowFile Repository with 0 records in 0 milliseconds
2024-12-19 09:58:55,320 INFO [Checkpoint FlowFile Repository] o.a.n.c.r.WriteAheadFlowFileRepository Initiating checkpoint of FlowFile Repository
2024-12-19 09:58:55,320 INFO [Checkpoint FlowFile Repository] o.a.n.c.r.WriteAheadFlowFileRepository Successfully checkpointed FlowFile Repository with 0 records in 0 milliseconds
2024-12-19 09:59:10,333 INFO [Cleanup Archive for default] o.a.n.c.repository.FileSystemRepository Successfully deleted 0 files (0 bytes) from archive
2024-12-19 09:59:10,334 INFO [Cleanup Archive for default] o.a.n.c.repository.FileSystemRepository Archive cleanup completed for container default; will now allow writing to this container. Bytes used = 141.27 GB, bytes free = 278.44 GB, capacity = 419.71 GB
2024-12-19 09:59:15,320 INFO [Checkpoint FlowFile Repository] o.a.n.c.r.WriteAheadFlowFileRepository Initiating checkpoint of FlowFile Repository
2024-12-19 09:59:15,320 INFO [Checkpoint FlowFile Repository] o.a.n.c.r.WriteAheadFlowFileRepository Successfully checkpointed FlowFile Repository with 0 records in 0 milliseconds
2024-12-19 09:59:35,321 INFO [Checkpoint FlowFile Repository] o.a.n.c.r.WriteAheadFlowFileRepository Initiating checkpoint of FlowFile Repository
2024-12-19 09:59:35,321 INFO [Checkpoint FlowFile Repository] o.a.n.c.r.WriteAheadFlowFileRepository Successfully checkpointed FlowFile Repository with 0 records in 0 milliseconds
2024-12-19 09:59:55,321 INFO [Checkpoint FlowFile Repository] o.a.n.c.r.WriteAheadFlowFileRepository Initiating checkpoint of FlowFile Repository
2024-12-19 09:59:55,321 INFO [Checkpoint FlowFile Repository] o.a.n.c.r.WriteAheadFlowFileRepository Successfully checkpointed FlowFile Repository with 0 records in 0 milliseconds
tail: '/opt/nifi/nifi-current/logs/nifi-app.log' has been replaced;  following new file
2024-12-19 10:00:10,361 INFO [Cleanup Archive for default] o.a.n.c.repository.FileSystemRepository Successfully deleted 0 files (0 bytes) from archive
2024-12-19 10:00:10,363 INFO [Cleanup Archive for default] o.a.n.c.repository.FileSystemRepository Archive cleanup completed for container default; will now allow writing to this container. Bytes used = 141.27 GB, bytes free = 278.44 GB, capacity = 419.71 GB
...

I tried many docker-compose.yml configurations on 2 ubuntu servers (18.04, Docker  24.0.2 and 24.04 Docker 27.4.0), several nifi versions. The simplest was this:
services:
  nifi_test:
    image: apache/nifi:latest
    container_name: nifi_test
    ports:
      - "8089:8080/tcp" # HTTP interface
      - "8449:8443/tcp" # HTTPS interface
    restart: unless-stopped

I exhausted ChatGPT and MistralAI on this issue. Any bright human insight would be much appreciated.
